# Prophecy autocomplete in PhpStorm

Tags: php, plugins, phpunit, phpstorm, prophecy

I use PhpStorm and [Prophecy](https://github.com/phpspec/prophecy) in PHPUnit tests.

I used plugin [PHPUnit Autocomplete Assistant](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7722) and it worked well until I updated to PhpStorm 2016.1.1. Plugin is disabled and this message shows on PhpStorm launch:

> Following plugins are incompatible with current IDE build: PHPUnit Autocomplete Assistant

Author doesn't answer for a week at his [GitHub issues](https://github.com/maxfilatov/phpuaca/issues/21) so I started looking for alternatives but cannot find any. Without such plugin Prophecy in PHPStorm is not pleasant - your editor is full of warnings, there are no autocompletes and so on.

Do you know any other tools for PHPStorm and Prophecy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forked the repo at gitHub and fixed the code - my merge request is open.

until you could use:
https://github.com/shopfe/phpuaca/releases/tag/1.3.2-beta

best regards

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **PhpStorm 2016.2+** you could create a file in your project root under `./.phpstorm.meta.php/prophecy.meta.php` with this content:

```
<?php

namespace PHPSTORM_META {
    override(\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::prophesize(0),
        map([
            '' => '@',
        ])
    );
}
```

After that (maybe also after restarting PhpStorm), autocomplete with prophecy would work like a charm:

[autocomplete example for PhpStorm with prophecy and meta file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtkDs.png)

Note the `extends TestCase` instead of the namespace lacking version for PHPUnit.

More info about this PhpStorm feature you could get here:
[PhpStorm Advanced Metadata](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata)

Answer (score 0):

The best plugin currently is the [PHPUnit Enhancement](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9674-phpunit-enhancement) which provides amazing support for Prophecy in PHPStorm. It's an open source project and works very well with latest PHPStorm releases. I can't imagine writing any test without it tbh since I use Prophecy & PHPUnit extensively.